# Compare Liferay's encrypted passwords and user input

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, liferay

I'm working on an application that shows information stored on a Liferay database. For doing that I made a web service, using Java, that reads data from the database. All queries are going well but I need a login section. The issue is that the password is encrypted and I don't know how to compare the password given by the user and the passwords I have in the database, that are encrypted.

**EDIT**: `passwords.encryption.algorithm` has the default value: `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000`

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Use the Source, Luke!](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/pwd/PwdAuthenticator.java)

Comment: Thank you! But i'm looking for something easier, if possible. Because I'll need a lot of other java classes, not only that one. But thank you anyway

Comment: Actually, it depends on the settings of your Liferay instance, because Liferay can use different encryption (it is set via `passwords.encryption.algorithm` property, by default set to `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1/160/128000`). Particular Encryptor implementations are in https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/pwd - choose the one you need.

Comment: Of course. We have the implementions in that link. But, is there any other way to do the comparation without using all these java classes? 

Because I'll need to use `PBKDF2PasswordEncryptor.java` and `import com.liferay.portal.PwdEncryptorException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.BigEndianCodec;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.SecureRandomUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Base64;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CharPool;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator;
`
@JozefChocholacek

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility class for password comparison.

[`PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil#isSameAsCurrentPassword(userId, newClearTextPwd)`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil.java)