# Liferay password comparison for custom log In

Tags: passwords, liferay-6

Scenario : I am trying to create custom log in functionality for liferay 6.1
In this, first I am asking email to user and I am checking, is this user is existing or new one. If it is existing then I will ask to fill password otherwise will ask him to create account.
My problem is, **How to compare user given password and password exist in DB**. User given password is plain text and DB saved password is in encoded form.
Any pointers on this will be helpful..Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The question is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101594/compare-liferays-encrypted-passwords-and-user-input , but I've answered it nevertheless (as I cannot mark it as duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a utility class for password comparison.

[`PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil#isSameAsCurrentPassword(userId, newClearTextPwd)`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil.java)